# Converting letters to numbers in a string that also contains numbers

Tags: cobol

I realize I have asked a similar question before, but the whole thing is more complicated than I thought.

To cut to the chase, I need to convert a string that contains numbers *and* letters into a string that only contains numbers, while keeping the numbers that were already there, in the right position.

The letters need to be converted to their corresponding position in the Alphabet + 9. So, A = 10, B= 11.... Z = 35.

So, basically, a string that looks like this: 
`'GB00LOYD1023456789A1B2'`

will have to become: 
`'161100212429131023456789101112'`.

I bolded the letters in both examples so you can see the difference more clearly. Depending on the input, the content will be longer or shorter than this example. Letters will be alternated by numbers and vice versa.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How would your encoded string be decoded? Is the pattern always 2-2-4-10--1-1-1-1 (letters-numbers-letters...) If it isn't then for instance your code `161100212429131023456789101112` could be interpreted as `GB00LOYDAM456789ABC`. I believe you should use the code that I gave you, which would encode the numerics as 0n and hence your string would become `16110000212429130100020304050607080910011102` which can easily be decoded back to your original string.

Comment: Thank you Magoo, I finally understand how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best way to do this?

That is a matter of opinion.

The REPLACING option of the INSPECT verb requires the replacing and replaced character strings to be the same size, so that's right out because you need to replace one character with two.  This is true at least for IBM COBOL.

*A way* to do this would be to loop through your input string and do a class check on each character.  Something like...

```
01  Stuff.
    05  in-posn    pic s999 packed-decimal value +0.
    05  out-posn   pic s999 packed-decimal value +1.
    05  in-string  pic x(022) value 'GB00LOYD1023456789A1B2'.
    05  out-string pic x(100) value spaces.
    05  replacer   pic x(002) value spaces.


perform varying in-posn from 1 by 1
until in-posn > length of in-string
    if in-string(in-posn:1) alphabetic
        evaluate in-string(in-posn:1)
          when 'A' move '10' to replacer
          when 'B' move '11' to replacer
          .
          .
          .
          when 'Z' move '35' to replacer
        end-evaluate
        string replacer delimited size
          into out-string
          pointer out-posn
        end-string
    else
        string in-string(in-posn:1) delimited size
          into out-string
          pointer out-posn
        end-string
    end-if
end-perform
```

There are variations available.  You could replace the evaluate with a couple of table lookups.  You could store the length of in-string before beginning the loop.  You could store in-string(in-posn:1) rather than hoping the compiler will do that for you.

This is just freehand but I think it conveys the idea.

Comment: It's tangential to the problem at hand, but GnuCOBOL has an intrinsic function (extension) `SUBSTITUTE(subject, pattern, replacement, [pattern-2, replacement-2, ...])`  where the patterns and replacements can all be variable widths.  Super handy.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clear and easy to understand solution